# I am not able to display the List<String> on Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

**Apex Class:-**

```
public class LightiningLstStrClass {
    @auraenabled
    public static list<String> LstStrMethod(){
        List<String> lststr=new List<String>{'aman','naman','billy'};
            return lststr;
    }
}
```

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component  controller="LightiningLstStrClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     <aura:attribute name="lststrvar" type="string[]" />
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.echo}"/>
    {!v.lststrvar}
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:-**

```
({
    echo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.LstStrMethod");
        action.setCallback(this, function(lststr) {
            alert(lststr.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.lststrvar",lststr.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide some more specifics? Does `v.lststrvar` get set inside of `echo()`? What does `lststr.getReturnValue()` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you run your code asynchronously and you need to notify Aura framework about UI update. In order to do it, wrap your callback into $A.getCallback().

```
({
    echo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.LstStrMethod");
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function(lststr) {
            alert(lststr.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.lststrvar",lststr.getReturnValue());
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```